# Xamarin Android Webview Linkify email addresses

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

I am trying to understand how I can get my WebView to "Linkify" the email addresses.  I want the email address to generate a hyperlink with mailto tag.  All the browsers seems to be able to do this automatically.  I am trying the following but I still do no get the links to show in the WebView UI.

```
HtmlString = "<html><head></head><body><label>Email:</label><span>xxx.yyy@example.com</span></body></html>"
SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(HtmlString);
Linkify.AddLinks(sp, MatchOptions.EmailAddresses);
string linkifiedContent = sp.ToString();

WebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL(BaseURL, linkifiedContent, MimeType, null, null);
```

Comment: why don't you put the mailto ref yourself?

Comment: That seems to be the solution I will go with.  The iOS WebView seems to automatically recognize the email address text and provide a link for it.  On Andorid, I will have to put the anchor tag myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Linkify](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Text.Util.Linkify/) is mostly used with TextView. It is used to create clickable links inside TextView.

In your case, you are already making use of WebView.
Hence, you can just add the email address inside `<a>` tags:

```
var HtmlString = "<html><head></head><body><label>Email:</label><span><a href='mailto:xxx.yyy@example.com'>xxx.yyy@example.com<a/></span></body></html>";

webView.LoadData(HtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

This should load your Html content perfectly.

[image]

Happy coding!